# Общее хранилище для LXC контейнеров

Tags: lvm, lxc

Имеется несколько LXC контейнеров, в качестве хранилища для rootfs используются LVM Logic volume.
Хочу чтоб у всех контейнеров был примонтирован в /mnt/shared общий LVM Logic volume, в который смогут писать/читать все контейнеры.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: а как вы запускаете контейнеры?

Comment: Как и все `lxc-start -n mycontainer`, ну и автостарт им в конфиги прописал, это как-то относится к вопросу?

Comment: прошу прощенья. проглядел LXC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Монтируете желаемое общее хранилище на хост-системе. Где угодно, пути внутри контейнера можно будет настроить любые другие.

Затем в конфиге каждого необходимого контейнера прописать [bind директории](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC#Bind_mounts_inside_the_container)

```
lxc.mount.entry=/path/in/host/mount_point mnt/shared none bind 0 0
```

Обратите внимание на то, что путь внутри контейнера должен быть указан относительный. Внутри контейнера пустая директория должна уже быть создана.

Всё, стартуете (или рестартуете) контейнеры и получаете общую для контейнеров директорию.

Права на чтение-запись - или использовать вседозволенность 0777 или играться с маппингом uid/gid между контейнерами и хост-системой. Тут подсказать не смогу, не экспериментировал.